# What does this oom log mean?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, out-of-memory

I am trying to understand the oom log here. I am not sure why a 'Normal free....' line is missing here. This is a custom imx board running linux. It has a 512MB RAM.

```
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: active_anon:22971 inactive_anon:212 isolated_anon:0
                                     active_file:371 inactive_file:450 isolated_file:0
                                     unevictable:22611 dirty:16 writeback:0 unstable:0
                                     slab_reclaimable:5434 slab_unreclaimable:23495
                                     mapped:2267 shmem:213 pagetables:554 bounce:0
                                     free:31476 free_pcp:83 free_cma:30052
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: Node 0 active_anon:91884kB inactive_anon:848kB active_file:1484kB inactive_file:1800kB unevictable:90444kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:9068kB dirty:64kB writ>
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:125904kB min:7028kB low:7568kB high:8108kB active_anon:91884kB inactive_anon:848kB active_file:1484kB inactive_file:1800kB unevictable:90444kB writepending:>
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 1182*4kB (UMEHC) 130*8kB (UMHC) 9*16kB (HC) 8*32kB (HC) 7*64kB (C) 6*128kB (C) 3*256kB (C) 2*512kB (C) 0*1024kB 1*2048kB (C) 2*4096kB (C) 1*8192kB (C) 2*16384kB>
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=32768kB
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=64kB
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: 2538 total pagecache pages
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: 0 pages in swap cache
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: Total swap = 0kB
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: 122880 pages RAM
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: 10212 pages reserved
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: 32768 pages cma reserved
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: 0 pages hwpoisoned
```

The other part of the log is:

```
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/rotomac.service,task=rotomac,pid=949,uid=0
Oct 06 05:20:08 IMX kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 949 (rotomac) total-vm:801480kB, anon-rss:83376kB, file-rss:5468kB, shmem-rss:4kB, UID:0 pgtables:352kB oom_score_adj:0
Oct 06 05:20:09 IMX kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2008 tx timeout
Oct 06 05:20:09 IMX kernel: watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
Oct 06 05:20:09 IMX systemd[1]: rotomac.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
```